# Creating a new React Native project is breaking in yarn 3 since React Native is looking for the node_modules folder

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I am initialising a new React Native app using yarn workspaces in yarn 3. But I get this error when I am running the command
`npx react-native init ReactNativeTypeScript --template react-native-template-typescript`

```
Error: Cannot find module '...ReactNativeTypeScript/node_modules/react-native/package.json'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at checkNodeVersion (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:306:21)
    at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:300:3)
    at createProject (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:249:3)
    at init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:200:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:153:7)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js' ]
}
```

I understand the error is because yarn 3 has moved to the shared cache method instead of node_modules. Is there a way this can work in yarn 3?

Answer (score 0):

That's because [Yarn 2+ doesn't support React Native through Plug'N'Play](https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp/#incompatible).

You can see the progress on that [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/27).

[This](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration#if-required-enable-the-node-modules-plugin) is the suggested workaround.